# Energy of classical fields in pre-relativistic physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, classical-field-theory

In non-relativistic physics, the electromagnetic energy in all space is given by:

$$E_{em} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left(\varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}^2 +
\frac{\mathbf{B}^2}{\mu_0}\right) \ \text{d}V$$

That energy added to the kinetic energy of the charged particles within the field remains constant (in the absence of other processes):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(E_{em} + E_{kin}\right) = 0$$

Although the relativistic case is different, since there is no well-defined local momentum energy tensor for the gravitational field, I wonder if we could attribute an energy to the Newtonian gravitational field such that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(E_{grav} + E_{kin}\right) = 0$$